# Postgres - partial pivot with crosstab

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

I'm struggling, and knowing the terminology to search for the answer is likely my problem as I can't imagine this is an edge case.

[dbfiddle available](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2c75cf9a1b18bb980ddd72953235d54e)

I have a table in Postgres 9.4:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, cust_id INTEGER,
    category VARCHAR, key INTEGER, value INTEGER
); 
INSERT INTO test (cust_id, category, key, value)
VALUES
    (1, 'alpha', 0,300),(1, 'bravo', 0,150),(1, 'alpha', 1,300),
    (1, 'bravo', 1,200),(1, 'alpha', 2,300),(1, 'bravo', 2,250),
    (2, 'alpha', 0,301),(2, 'bravo', 0,151),(2, 'alpha', 1,301),
    (2, 'bravo', 1,201),(2, 'alpha', 2,301),(2, 'bravo', 2,251),
    (3, 'alpha', 0,302),(3, 'bravo', 0,152),(3, 'alpha', 1,302),
    (3, 'bravo', 1,202),(3, 'alpha', 2,302),(3, 'bravo', 2,252);


 id | cust_id | category | key | value 
----+---------+----------+-----+-------
  1 |       1 | alpha    |   0 |   300
  2 |       1 | bravo    |   0 |   150
  3 |       1 | alpha    |   1 |   300
  4 |       1 | bravo    |   1 |   200
  5 |       1 | alpha    |   2 |   300
  6 |       1 | bravo    |   2 |   250
  7 |       2 | alpha    |   0 |   301
  8 |       2 | bravo    |   0 |   151
  9 |       2 | alpha    |   1 |   301
 10 |       2 | bravo    |   1 |   201
 11 |       2 | alpha    |   2 |   301
 12 |       2 | bravo    |   2 |   251
 13 |       3 | alpha    |   0 |   302
 14 |       3 | bravo    |   0 |   152
 15 |       3 | alpha    |   1 |   302
 16 |       3 | bravo    |   1 |   202
 17 |       3 | alpha    |   2 |   302
 18 |       3 | bravo    |   2 |   252
(18 rows)
```

I'd like to query the results to look like the following:

```
 cust_id | category |  0  |  1  |  2  
---------+----------+-----+-----+-----
       1 | alpha    | 300 | 300 | 300 
       1 | bravo    | 150 | 200 | 250 
       2 | alpha    | 301 | 301 | 301
       2 | bravo    | 151 | 201 | 251
       3 | alpha    | 302 | 302 | 302
       3 | bravo    | 152 | 202 | 252
(6 rows)
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    crosstab(
        'SELECT cust_id,category,key,value FROM test ORDER BY cust_id,category,key',
        $$values ('0'::INT),
        ('1'::INT),
        ('2'::INT) $$
    ) AS ct (
        "cust_id" INT, "category" TEXT, "0" INT,
        "1" INT, "2" INT
    );
```

which nets me (lacking the bravo category rows and uses bravo values for columns 1,2,3):

```
 cust_id | category |  0  |  1  |  2  
---------+----------+-----+-------
       1 | alpha    | 150 | 200 | 250 
       2 | alpha    | 151 | 201 | 251
       3 | alpha    | 152 | 202 | 252
(2 rows)
```

I get closer with the following by removing the `cust_id` field and limiting to a single id:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    crosstab(
        'SELECT category,key,value FROM test WHERE cust_id = 1 ORDER BY category,key',
        $$values ('0'::INT),
        ('1'::INT),
        ('2'::INT) $$
    ) AS ct (
        "category" TEXT, "0" INT,
        "1" INT, "2" INT
    );
```

but this only gives the result for a single `cust_id`, but I need this for all customers:

```
 category |  0  |  1  |  2  
----------+-----+-------
 alpha    | 300 | 300 | 300 
 bravo    | 150 | 200 | 250 
(2 rows)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2c75cf9a1b18bb980ddd72953235d54e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select cust_id , category  
    , max(case when key = 0 then value end) "0" 
    , max(case when key = 1 then value end) "1"
    , max(case when key = 2 then value end) "2"
from test
group by cust_id , category
order by cust_id , category
```